# Dropdown in floating buttons with icons

Tags: css, materialize

I use materializecss and want to implement dropdown in floating button with icon inside.

Here is the markup:

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-button btn-floating btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" :data-activates="'dropdown_' + order.id">
    <i class="small material-icons">more_horiz</i>
  </a>
  <ul :id="'dropdown_' + order.id" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Which is basically the same as in docs, however instead of simple button I use floating button and an icon inside. Without `<i>` it works fine, however with `<i>` I got `display: none;` for the dropdown.

How can I fix this?

**update**

Worked for me after updating to `0.98.2`

Comment: Seems to work here https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/xdVjwJ. Could the problem be related to something else in your code?

Comment: Worked when I changed version to 0.98.2, I had 0.98.1, thanks for your tip-off, I just checked out which version you used

Comment: How about in the case where the floating button is fixed. Nothing seems to happen on this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGBMZp